# Laravel's caching configuration

Tags: php, laravel, caching, pdo

I have deployed a website made with Laravel to my server. I have changed all the configurations but when I run it on browser, it gives me PDO error.
I figured out that Laravel configuration has not been changed even though I have.
It was certain that laravel was caching my old db configurations, so

I tried

```
php artisan:cache clear
```

But it didn't work.
Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan config:clear` for `Remove the configuration cache file`

Comment: Thank you, I had to manually delete bootstrap/cache/config.php.
Your answer worked.